# How to insert text into Textboxes dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a Project in C#, i need to insert text into textfields which are more then 250,
i stored the data in an array of string , now i have to insert data from array into these 250 textboxes in sequence like

```
textbox1.Text=StringArray[1];
textbox2.Text=StringArray[2];
       .               .
       .               .
       .               .
textbox250.Text=StringArray[250];
```

i google it no positive results ,
i did code to clear text from all the textboxes, i.e

```
Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;
func = (controls) =>
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
       if (control is TextBox)
          (control as TextBox).Clear();
       else
          func(control.Controls);
 };
 func(Controls);
```

i tried to insert text like this

```
 Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;
 int i=0;
 func = (controls) =>
 {
     foreach (Control control in controls)
     {
         if (control is TextBox)
            (control as TextBox).Text = result_set[i++].ToString();
         else
            func(control.Controls);

     }
 };

 func(Controls);
```

but got an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'.

Comment: `got some error` What error did you get?

Comment: the error is 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in 1.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: yes the textboxes are already on the page

Comment: the exception tells you that there are probably more textboxes on the page than texts in the string. You could check for the length of the array before access

Comment: how about if you return i along with the result_set[i++] to confirm the index is working the way you want?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you access a member outside of the array. It could be because you have other textboxes on the page which are found by the loop and then your array index runs out of range. Maybe you could do something like this:

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= StringArray.Length; i++)
 {
     // I don't know which technology you use, it might be a different method to find
     Control control = controlCollection.FindByName("Textbox" + i.ToString(); 
     if (control is TextBox)
        (control as TextBox).Text = StringArray[i];
 }
```

Comment: slfan thanks for reply , but the problem here is that its not a web page its a desktop app, secondly the textboxes are already created..

Comment: sorry, but then you should remove the asp.net tag.

Comment: is it about winforms, wpf, silverlight, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute "index" to every textbox on your page with the index of the array, and attach a function to the event "OnInit" in order to insert the text. An example:

PAGE:

```
[asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnInit="setText" index="1"][/asp:TextBox]

[asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnInit="setText" index="2"][/asp:TextBox]

...
```

CODE BEHIND:

public void setText(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

```
    TextBox tbx;
    tbx = sender;
    tbx.Text = StringArray[sender.attributes["index"]];

}
```

Hope this helps!